# Editable List with checkbox

Tags: android

I want to create a editable list with checkboxes for creating todo (just like checkboxes in Google Keep). Is there a control to achieve this ?

Edit: See the Image of Google Keep List.

[image]

Comment: `just like checkboxes in Google Keep` isn't enough to explain the problem. Do explain the problem.

Comment: you need to create a custom item layout for your list. 
checkbox and EditText.

Comment: @ADM I have edited my question

Comment: I never used Google Keep. Looking at the list its looks like list item having a `CheckBox` and a `Edittext` . `Edittext` toggles state(editable/non-editable) on `CheckBox` toggle .

Comment: You can write on edit text just like todo, and checkbox strikethrough the edit text, and the item will move to bottom, as if it's completed..

Answer (score 1):

There is no editable Checkbox provided by android what you can do is set listeners on your checkboxes, and then have to capture the events like when checkbox is checked and when is it unchecked to make your editexts work the way you want.A sample way to start is :

```
CheckBox someCheckBox= (CheckBox) findViewById (R.id.someID);
someCheckBox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
            //CODE TO MAKE THE EDITTEXT ENABLED         
    }
    else 
       //CODE TO MAKE THE EDITTEXT DISABLED     

  }
});
```

However there are other ways too,to achieve this task, but you can kick off with this right away. Hope it helps.

Comment: Is there anyway I can repeat a control in android

Comment: yes , go through https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview